# Shopping cart in java with ArrayList seeing if a list contains an item

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having trouble with case 4, i want it to search for an item in the arrayList and say it is in the cart or not in the cart but every time i run the program it says an item in the cart is actually in the cart and an item i did not add is in the cart. how do i declare it to say i do have the item the user typed in and say you don't have that item the user typed in.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String nameOfItem = " ";
    double priceOfItem = 0.0;
    int quantityOfItem = 0;
    String choice = "y";
    String choice2 = " ";
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");

    ArrayList<Item> cart1 = new ArrayList<Item>();

    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

        System.out.print("What is the item you want? ");
        nameOfItem = keyboard.next();

        System.out.print("What is the price? ");
        priceOfItem = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("How many do you want? ");
        quantityOfItem = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Do you wish to continue?(y/n) ");
        choice = keyboard.nextLine();

        cart1.add(new Item(nameOfItem, quantityOfItem, priceOfItem));

        System.out.println();
        {

            while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("1. Display the contents of the cart\n" + "2. Add another item to the cart\n"
                        + "3. Remove an item from the cart\n" + "4. Search an item in the cart\n"
                        + "5. If done shopping");
                choice2 = keyboard.nextLine();

                switch (choice2) {

                case "1":
                    double total = 0;
                    for (Item item : cart1) {
                        System.out.println(item);
                        total += item.getPrice() * item.getQuantity();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Total of your items: " + df.format(total));
                    break;

                case "2":
                    System.out.print("What item do you want? ");
                    nameOfItem = keyboard.nextLine();

                    System.out.print("What is the price? ");
                    priceOfItem = keyboard.nextDouble();

                    System.out.print("How many do you want? ");
                    quantityOfItem = keyboard.nextInt();
                    keyboard.nextLine();

                    cart1.add(new Item(nameOfItem, quantityOfItem, priceOfItem));
                    System.out.println();
                    break;

                case "3":
                    for (Item item : cart1) {
                        System.out.println(item);
                    }
                    ArrayList<Item> cart2 = new ArrayList<Item>();

                    System.out.println(
                            "\nWhat item would you like to delete?\nAll quantities of the item will be deleted");
                    nameOfItem = keyboard.nextLine();

                    cart2.add(new Item(nameOfItem, quantityOfItem, priceOfItem));
                    for (Item item : cart1) {
                        if (item.getProduct().equals(nameOfItem)) {
                            cart2.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    cart1.removeAll(cart2);
                    System.out.println();
                    break;

                case "4":


                    System.out.println("What item are you looking for?");
                    nameOfItem = keyboard.nextLine();


                    for (Item item : cart1) {
                        if (cart1.contains(item)) 
                        {
                System.out.println("You do have that item in your cart!");
                        } else {
                System.out.println("You do not have that item in your cart, press\n2 on the "
                            + "next screen to add it to your cart");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                case "5":
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid choice, pick again!!!!");
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
System.out.println("What item are you looking for?");

nameOfItem = keyboard.nextLine();

boolean found = false;


for (Item item : cart1) {
    if (item.getName().equals(nameOfItem)) {
        found = true;
    }
}

if (found) {
   System.out.println("You do have that item in your cart!");
} else {
    System.out.println("You do not have that item in your cart, press\n2 on the "
                        + "next screen to add it to your cart");
}
```

Comment: what is `cart` referring to? I see you declare `cart1` and `cart2` but I don't see `cart` anywhere

Comment: It was supposed to say cart1 not cart.  I started at cart1 in my arraylist

Comment: @TanaBanana check edited answer. This answer assumes that your `Item` class has a `getName()` method which returns the name of the item as a string

Comment: Glad I could help :)